# How to open lightbox contact us form with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

**This is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Lightbox</title>

    <meta name="description" lang="en" content="Lightbox is a script used to overlay images on the current page. It's a snap to setup and works on all modern browsers."/>
    <meta name="author" content="Lokesh Dhakar">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/demopage/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla%7CMontserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <section id="examples" class="examples-section">
                
<a href="https://from100.wufoo.com/forms/sfzxgmx02j3w8g/" data-lightbox="example-1"    onclick="window.open(this.href,  null, 'height=668, width=680, toolbar=0, location=0, status=1, scrollbars=1, resizable=1'); return false">Please fill out my form.</a>

                </section>   
                
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>

    <script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2196019-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

when run this code, I want show a contact form as light box. Now it shows not properly, May i know, what is exact way to correct it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: May i know, why vote down? what is my mistake in my post?

Comment: I haven't voted down ... yet. But reason I would is that you have not shown at all what you have tried regarding a lightbox with the `onclick` event.  Instead you have shown something to do with `window.open`  Go to the lightbox page and have a read there first, then try something and if you're still stuck make a specific question as opposed to "I can't do this and I'm too lazy to go to google and read and learn, can you guys please do it all for me"

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: I replaced lightbox() with window.open, but still i didn't get it. And i am new to jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery-ui to do this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Modal Popup</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- <button id="dialog_trigger">open the dialog</button> -->
<a href="#" id="dialog_trigger">open the dialog</a>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title="Dialog Title"><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://from100.wufoo.com/forms/sfzxgmx02j3w8g/"></iframe></div>
<script>
$( "#dialog_trigger" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: 'top' ,
    title: 'EDIT',
    draggable: false,
    width : 800,
    height : 770, 
    resizable : true,
    modal : true,
    open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
});
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Change what you need in the code.

Comment: What you mean "lightbox" ? The code is working well, i don't understand what you need =( Why it doesn't works to you?

Comment: I need, when click outside of that form, it will be closed.

Comment: Done, now it closes when clicked outside. ^^